# How to List Matrices Names in Excel?

Tags: excel, list, vba, matrix, names

I gave names to some cells ranges in Excel (select cells, right click, define name), in order to recall them as matrices. 
Is it possible to have a list of the named matrices that I created this way?

Answer (score 1):

Is this useful? Press `F3` and click `Paste Names`

from: 
http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/09/20/show-all-names-excel/

Answer (score 1):

You can just look at the list in the **"name box"** as shown in the following image:

[image]

The image was taken from [this site](http://www.extendoffice.com).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. 
However I found that there is just a "name manager" under the "Formulas" tab, which provides the most complete access.